PHP sends curl to submit a login request, it receives code 302, and the automatic jump will return Code 411
All tests can be completed in postman, and the Location page after login is displayed correctly.
However, when the postman output as php-curl:
<?php
include('php/simple_html_dom.php');
$username = 'username';
$password = 'password';
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => 'https://somesite.com/',
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 10,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
  CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'GET',
  CURLOPT_HEADER => false,
  CURLOPT_NOBODY => false,
  // CURLOPT_COOKIE => '',
  CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR => dirname(__FILE__) .'/cookie.txt',
  CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE => dirname(__FILE__) .'/cookie.txt',
  CURLOPT_USERAGENT=> 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/129.0.0.0 Safari/537.36',
  // CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array('Transfer-Encoding: chunked')
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);
// echo $response;
// exit();
$html = str_get_html($response);
$htmlFormData= [];
foreach($html->find('input') as $input) {
    $htmlFormData[$input->name]=$input->value;
}
foreach($html->find('#header h3') as $h3) {
    if($h3->plaintext === 'Login'){//when page title is Login
        $htmlFormData['DES_Group'] = 'LOGIN';
        $htmlFormData['DES_JSE'] = '1';
        $htmlFormData['ctl00$ctl00$plcMain$contentMain$ucLogin$ctlAccountNumber$txtText'] = $username;
        $htmlFormData['ctl00$ctl00$plcMain$contentMain$ucLogin$ctlAuthorisationCode$txtText'] = $password;
        curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
          CURLOPT_URL => 'https://somesite.com/',
          CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
          CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'POST',
          CURLOPT_HEADER => true,
          CURLOPT_NOBODY => false,
          // CURLOPT_POSTREDIR => 0,
          CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
          CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
          CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
          CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
          CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
          CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR => dirname(__FILE__) .'/cookie.txt',
          CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE => dirname(__FILE__) .'/cookie.txt',
          CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => http_build_query($htmlFormData),
          CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array('Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded')
        ));
        $response = curl_exec($curl);
        $httpCode = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

        $effectiveUrl = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL);

        echo "HTTP Code: ".$httpCode."<br>";
        echo "Effective URL: ".$effectiveUrl."<br>";
        echo $response;
    }else{
      echo "Logged!. cookie.txt already contains .ASPXFORMSAUTH";
    }
}

the following response header is returned:
HTTP Code: 411
Effective URL: https://somesite.com/booking/
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Date: Sun, 20 Oct 2024 00:00:43 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 126
Connection: keep-alive
Set-Cookie: AWSALB=xMfAME0xDTNJ17NWiuA4syXcTE0CUWzRqUO63dFLazoxuBPtYZfVAYsolxrmOUMgzRADJXDq; Expires=Sun, 27 Oct 2024 00:00:40 GMT; Path=/
Set-Cookie: AWSALBCORS=xMMUBtfAMA4syXcTE0CUWDiPktKmavB8VuIhLM2eLGPw+tEzoxuBPsolxrmOUMgzRX1P2QKADJXDq; Expires=Sun, 27 Oct 2024 00:00:40 GMT; Path=/; SameSite=None; Secure
Cache-Control: private, no-store, must-revalidate
Location: /booking/
X-FRAME-OPTIONS: SAMEORIGIN
Set-Cookie: CMSPreferredUICulture=en-nz; expires=Mon, 20-Oct-2025 00:00:43 GMT; path=/
Set-Cookie: .ASPXFORMSAUTH=AD600CA697E4A07EB134CF9F12813F736914DC94F2164A4A9A19BC42ABF845597F0231A83917EA97B399; path=/; HttpOnly
Set-Cookie: TS01c9af0a=0117e34adee26391d0af81086688506aff9d5cec88ee47f19d31f9cdd4e2d070d876c3689d8d9; Path=/; Secure; HTTPOnly

HTTP/1.1 411 Length Required
Date: Sun, 20 Oct 2024 00:00:44 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=us-ascii
Content-Length: 344
Connection: keep-alive
Set-Cookie: AWSALB=oTIj1ThOZyA7Bz8OBtcjVdgcb6+oGq3Annmnng9+XCFsipA1vSVA24NPMiWOT4D3v25UvuE+XtHHd; Expires=Sun, 27 Oct 2024 00:00:43 GMT; Path=/
Set-Cookie: AWSALBCORS=oTIj1ThOZyA7Bz8DAIQB/8OHS8U60WjnmloGq3Annmnng9+XCFsipA1vST/i9yr9NPMiWOT4D3v25UI4JFFdvuE+XtHHd; Expires=Sun, 27 Oct 2024 00:00:43 GMT; Path=/; SameSite=None; Secure
Set-Cookie: TS01c9af0a=0117e34adee263913af8108668cec892bd9209d31f9cdd4e2dec5070d876c3689d8d9; Path=/; Secure; HTTPOnly

If you set "CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION = false" and then manually request the URL('https://somesite.com/') again, I can correctly jump to the page after login.
The first POST Login request of curl is to submit the form. Here Curl will automatically add Content-length and return a 302 redirect.
It is not possible to set the redirection parameters in the first curl.
I tried to manually request the redirect address again and the correct page was returned without setting Content-length.

HTTP/1.1 411 Length Required - have you tried adding the length of formdata to the request to satisfy that requirement?

Did you see this post...? Maybe this could help you. How to Fix 411

I don't know how to set the header parameter Content-length in the redirect, if I set Content-length inside first curl this refers to the parameters of the POST and not the GET parameters after the redirect.

This is expected behavior according to the Fetch standard. Any redirected requests from a 302 response should be converted to GET. See the note on https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/302.
The server should respond with 307 to keep POST.
If you can't control the server's response, you'll have to use the manual route.
